# Input validation of at least 8 characters and only combinations of letters and numbers using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm creating a validation on input fields. Its validation is a "8 Characters minimum" and "only contains a combination of letters and numbers".

I've made the script as below but it's still not what I want. Currently, the errors that appear are one by one, not all at once.

For example, if I type **"a12"** it should show a **"8 characters minimum"** error. and if I type **"a12."** or **"a12@"** , the **"8 character minimum"** error will disappear and only show **"only contains a combination of letters and numbers"** error.

The error should be `8 character minimum, only contains a combination of letters and numbers`

how to solve this?

```js
$("[name='testing']").on('keyup', function(){
  const getValue = $(this).val();
  const numbers = /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/;
  
  if(getValue.length < 8){
    $('.error').html('<span class="min-char">8 character minimum</span>')
    
    if(getValue.match(numbers)){
      $('.error .combine-pass').remove()
    }else{
      $('.error').html('<span class="combine-pass">Combination of letters and numbers</span>')
    }
    
  }else{
    $('.error .min-char').remove()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="testing">
<div class="error"></div>
```

Comment: That suggests you need to iterate through all rules every time, and concatenate a suitable error message. It looks like you are replacing the error every time a new issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I used regular expression validation and javascript event listeners to implement the use case.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("input");
element.addEventListener("input", validate);

function validate(e) {
  let value = e.target.value
  const regEx = /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/
  if (!regEx.test(value) && value.length < 8) {
    document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "8 character minimum, only contains a combination of letters and numbers";
  } else if (!regEx.test(value)) {
    document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "only contains a combination of letters and numbers";
  } else if (regEx.test(value)) {
    if (value.length < 8) {
      document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "8 characters minimum";
      return
    }
    document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "";
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<div id="errorMsg"></div>
```

**Please upvote if you find this answer useful.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check input text contains special character/s then use regex: `rg1 = /[^a-z0-9]/gi`.

If you want to check input text contains exactly 8 charcters (letters & numbers) then use regex: `rg2 = /^[a-z0-9]{8}$/gi`

using this two regex you can clearly validate your input and so output accordingly.

```
if(rg1.test(txt)) return "only contains a combination of letters and numbers";
else if(!rg2.test(txt)) return "8 characters minimum";
```

Don't require the length validation. If the input text length is exactly 8, then `rg2` return `true` otherwise `false`.